# JavaScript package to run dominance analysis for calculation variable importance

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, statistics, regression

I'm looking for a JavaScript package to run the dominance analysis (Budescu) to calculate variable importance.

Dominance analysis is a statistical method used to determine the order of “dominance” or “relative importance” of predictors in an established linear regression model and for a given set of p predictor variables.

I found some packages that can run it in Python and R languages, but I don't know if that possible to do with javascript.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any package for running the Dominance analysis (Shapley regression) in Javascript as it can be done in R (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dominanceanalysis/dominanceanalysis.pdf) or Python (https://pypi.org/project/dominance-analysis/) to calculate variable importance.

Relying on the comparison of the Dominance Analysis (Shapley Regression) and Johnson's Relative Weights analysis (https://www.displayr.com/shapley-vs-relative-weights/) we can see that results computed by both approaches are very similar (in most cases identical).

Citing the foregoing we can use Johnson's Relative Weights analysis (JRW) instead of the Dominance analysis.

JRW analysis implementation with Javascript realized in the johnsons-relative-weights npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/johnsons-relative-weights).

Steps of JRW analysis and its JS implementation are briefly described in this article: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/johnsons-relative-weights-analysis-implementation-with-javascript-d85393c0bbb4